# subtract the values of two columns using awk or bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have some  text files as shown below. I would like to subtract the values of column 2 and 4 and need to create a  new column to the output.

```
co1  co2   co3    co4

r1  15.2  13.0   21.4
r2  23    15     15.7
r3  14    8      12
```

desired output

```
co1  co2   co3   co4   diff.    

r1  15.2  13.0   21.4   -6.2
r2  23    15     15.7   7.3
r3  14    8      12     2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note: You could put the awk commands all on one line, but this is tidier (plus more transparent and easier to modify if need be).

This `so.awk` script:

```
NR==1{print $0, "   diff.\n"}
NR>2{printf("%s\t%5.1f\n", $0, $2-$4)}
```

gives:

```
co1  co2   co3   co4     diff.

r1  15.2  13.0   21.4    -6.2
r2  23    15     15.7     7.3
r3  14    8      12       2.0
```

Given your data in file `data.txt` issue this command:

```
 awk -f so.awk data.txt
```

(You may have to adjust the formatting to fit your exact needs)

Answer (score 12):

This one-liner works:

```
awk 'NR == 1 { $5 = "diff." } NR >= 3 { $5 = $2 - $4 } 1' <input.txt
```

It gives:

```
co1 co2 co3 co4 diff.

r1 15.2 13.0 21.4 -6.2
r2 23 15 15.7 7.3
r3 14 8 12 2
```

If you want to separate fields by tabs, this is wat you want:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } NR == 1 { $5 = "diff." } NR >= 3 { $5 = $2 - $4 } 1' <input.txt
```

Answer (score 11):

The one-liner by Taku Miyakawa can be simplified if you don't have a header:

```
awk '{ $5 = $2 - $4 } 1' input.txt > inputdiff.txt
```

Or with tab separation:

```
awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } { $5 = $2 - $4 } 1' input.txt > inputdiff.txt
```