# How do I save the outputs to a folder using awk or bash?

Tags: bash, awk

This is the continuation of my previous question [subtract the values of two columns using awk or bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005080/subtract-the-values-of-two-columns-using-awk-or-bash).
I have 200 files. I would like to save the outputs from each file to a folder.The file names in this folder should be the name of parent files. How can I do this with Awk or Bash?

Comment: Be explicit about what code you're using, preferably by including it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple `for` loop will do the job:

```
for i in *; do mkdir "$i"_dir; awk -f your_awk_script.awk "$i" > "$i"_dir/out
```

Explanation: here this command uses `for`, which loops over all files in current directory, then it creates a directory with name based on `i`-th file name using `mkdir` command.