# use awk to compute difference of two columns

Tags: bash, awk

I wanted to compute some column differences in a csv file, say

file:

```
item1,0.01,0.1
item2,0.02,0.2
item3,0.03,0.3
```

expected output file:

```
item1,0.01,0.1,-0.09
item2,0.02,0.2,-0.18
item3,0.03,0.3,-0.27
```

I tried something like this:

```
awk -F, '{print $2-$3 "," $0}'
```

and got the difference in the first column, but unable to put it in the 4th!
The following didn't work and gave me strange result like: ',$0[original line]'.

```
awk -F, '{print $0 "," $2-$3}'
```

What's happening here? And how to fix this?
I'm using GNU awk under bash.

Also tried tips from: [subtract the values of two columns using awk or bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005080/subtract-the-values-of-two-columns-using-awk-or-bash)
e.g.,

```
awk '{ $4 = $2 - $3 } 1'
```

but didn't get expected result either. What does that '1' do in the end of the command?

UPDATE:
I think there is something wrong in my real data file:

```
fa8befbbf03c5539363996a576d5df20,0.725571036339,0.654274122734
fb51f93cc69b6be7375f518092330197,0.941242694855,0.888087145568
fc35b866ed1b3176193ccab251394cf2,0.0169462561607,0.10700264598
fd43d08452687499c00dc62511e5fb8c,0.13467258215,0.197959610293
fe4e8d77fa1770a331b3fca0f712d1a2,0.732236325741,0.302812807639
ff339fd5b4bfc7e916591ecc88286584,0.0581884384155,0.276936129794
ff34734e135192a75838d18e870bec86,0.941790342331,0.680042603973
ff34be2a8759cadcae3ea0fc74d7ef7e,0.111128211021,0.0429052298147
ff910f590b8d19dbc135d69a4bb6dc3e,0.400317430496,0.623828952199
ff9be3a6286f90d0b3ce7b049ac1cb9a,0.0130054950714,0.0511833470525
```

This seems to break the proposed two solutions below.

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="," '{$4=$2-$3}1' file2.csv 
,0.07129693c5539363996a576d5df20,0.725571036339,0.654274122734
,0.05315559b6be7375f518092330197,0.941242694855,0.888087145568
,-0.0900564b3176193ccab251394cf2,0.0169462561607,0.10700264598
,-0.063287687499c00dc62511e5fb8c,0.13467258215,0.197959610293
,0.429424a1770a331b3fca0f712d1a2,0.732236325741,0.302812807639
,-0.218748bfc7e916591ecc88286584,0.0581884384155,0.276936129794
,0.26174835192a75838d18e870bec86,0.941790342331,0.680042603973
,0.068223759cadcae3ea0fc74d7ef7e,0.111128211021,0.0429052298147
,-0.2235128d19dbc135d69a4bb6dc3e,0.400317430496,0.623828952199
,-0.0381779f90d0b3ce7b049ac1cb9a,0.0130054950714,0.0511833470525
```

They both worked well on the example data file.

Thanks!

Comment: Your second version works for me.

Comment: Demo: http://ideone.com/JqgVDV

Comment: updated with a real example.

Comment: Still works for me: http://ideone.com/Lo6lKM

Comment: Your original file has CRLF line breaks. Use `dos2unix` to get rid of the CR characters.

Comment: hm..good to know. could this be awk version issue? i'm using GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: the file is generated under linux, so that CRLF could be from copy&paste to SO website

Comment: No, they're not in the SO website, I'm assuming it's what's happening based on the result you're seeing.

Comment: If I create the CSV file with CRLF line endings, I get exactly the output you're seeing.

Comment: What are you using to create the CSV file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146577/discussion-between-galactica-and-barmar).

Comment: As you've been told already your input file DOES contain CRLFs. What you're describing is the classic symptom of that. Use `dos2unix` or similar to remove them. This has nothing to do with awk versions or anything else.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS="," '{$4=$2-$3}1' file1
# Or awk -F, -v OFS="," '{$(NF+1)=$2-$3}1' file1
item1,0.01,0.1,-0.09
item2,0.02,0.2,-0.18
item3,0.03,0.3,-0.27
```

`$NF` is the last field.
`$(NF+1)` is one extra field after last field
`OFS` is the output field separator
`F` (or `FS`) is the input field separator

What the `1` does:
awk syntax always follows the rule `condition{actions}`
You can omit `conditions` or you can omit `actions` but not both.

If you omit `conditions`, condition `1` is assumed = True = Always do the following `{actions}`

If you omit `{actions}` , default action is performed --> `{print $0}`

So a single `1` is a simple true condition = perform default action = `{print $0}` - as `$0` has been so far modified

Comment: great walk through on the syntax thanks! so '{$4=$2-$3}1' is equivalent to '1{$4=$2-$3}1{print $0}', correct?

Comment: @galactica Exactly - completely equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat items.csv 
item1,0.01,0.1
item2,0.02,0.2
item3,0.03,0.3

$ awk -F, -v OFS=',' '{ print $0,$2-$3 }' items.csv 
item1,0.01,0.1,-0.09
item2,0.02,0.2,-0.18
item3,0.03,0.3,-0.27
```