# bash: sorting based on numerical distance

Tags: bash

I have a file containing a list of people with their gender and age like this:

```
name1    M    73.2
name2    M    31.5
name3    F    20.3
name4    F    55.0
...
```

Is there a bash one-liner to sort this list based on numerical distances to a given age, say 30.0, so that the result becomes:

```
name2    M    31.5
name3    F    20.3
name4    F    55.0
name1    M    73.2
```

Comment: Have you tried the `sort` command?

Comment: Thanks, but you did not get my question.

Comment: The output is simply ordered by age, which is indistinguishable from sorting by difference from any number below all the numbers in that column. In any case, what you need is to add another column to the data with the offset from 20 and sort by that column.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! Can I edit my question to avoid the coincidence and see if other people have a better solution?

Comment: Sure thing. Although both of these problems have been solved before on this site: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44530875/96588), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6438940/96588).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have edited my question for you to re-open it. Your solution takes two steps of subtraction and sorting, but I am curious if there is even a simpler one. Thank you again!

Comment: Neither of the suggested questions provides an answer to this question, IMO.

Comment: I agree that neither suggestions can work directly, but they are still helpful information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a similar manner, if there is a need to preserve the line format on the original, instead of printing the first three field, you can use a variable and truncate after the third field of the results from `sort`, e.g.

```
awk 'function abs(v) { return v < 0 ? -v : v }
    { print $0"\t"abs($NF-30) }' file | 
sort -k4n |
awk '{ out=$0; print substr(out, 0, match (out,$3)+length($3)) }'
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your example file in the file named `file`, you would get:

```
$ awk 'function abs(v) { return v < 0 ? -v : v }
>     { print $0"\t"abs($NF-30) }' file |
> sort -k4n |
> awk '{ out=$0; print substr(out, 0, match (out,$3)+length($3)) }'
name2    M    31.5
name3    F    20.3
name4    F    55.0
name1    M    73.2
```

(**note:** you can just select-copy the original `awk` expression and then in an xterm with `file` in the current working directory, middle-mouse-paste to test)

Answer (score 1):

#### Any version of Awk

```
awk -v ref=30.0 '{ print $1, $2, $3, ($3 < ref) ? ref - $3 : $3 - ref }' |
sort -k4,4n |
awk '{ print $1, $2, $3 }'
```

Add the distance from the reference age as an extra column, sort on it, remove it.  You could use `cut` for the removal operation if you prefer.  If you use GNU Awk, you can do it all in `awk`.  There are ways to preserve the spacing if that's important to you.

You can write it all on one line if you insist; that's your choice.

#### All-in-one using GNU Awk

Checking the [GNU Awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) shows that there isn't an `abs()` built-in function, which is a little surprising. GNU Awk does have the [`asort()` and `asorti()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Array-Sorting-Functions) functions which can be used to sort the data internally, thereby allowing the code to use a single call to `awk` and no calls to the `sort` command.  This also preserves the spacing in the original data.

This variation uses the 'square of the distance' idea suggested by [zhihao_li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7205275/zhihao-li) in their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61221612/15168).

```
gawk -v ref=48.0 '
function comp_idx(i1, v1, i2, v2) {
    if (i1+0 < i2+0) return -1; else if (i1+0 > i2+0) return +1; else return 0;
}
    { data[($3-ref)^2] = $0 }
END { 
      n = asorti(data, results, "comp_idx")
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) print data[results[i]]
    }' "$@"
```

The `+0` operations in the `comp_idx` function are necessary to force `awk` to treat the index values as numbers rather than strings.  Without those, the sort order was based on the lexicographical (not numeric) order of the squared distances.  If a single line is important, you could write that all on one line, but you'd need a sprinkling of semicolons added too.  I don't recommend it.

You could revise the code into a more comprehensive shell script that takes the age as an argument that's passed to Awk (the `-v ref=30.0` mechanism).  That's more fiddly than difficult.   As it stands, it just processes the files it is given — or standard input if no files are given.

With the sample data, the output for the reference age of 48.0 is:

```
name4    F    55.0
name2    M    31.5
name1    M    73.2
name3    F    20.3
```

Change the reference age from 48.0 to 30.0 as in the question and the result is:

```
name2    M    31.5
name3    F    20.3
name4    F    55.0
name1    M    73.2
```

Comment: Something about *minds thinking alike*. I was wrapping up when I saw your answer. I do like the simplicity you managed.

Comment: Thanks.  I've just been checking the [GNU Awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) and there doesn't appear to be an `abs` built-in function, which is a little surprising.  GNU Awk does have the [`asort()` and `asorti()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Array-Sorting-Functions) functions which could probably be used to sort the data internally, thereby allowing the code to use a single call to `awk` and no calls to the `sort` command.

Comment: It doesn't, I actually searched it and found there was none -- than then found the SO question related to it -- must be a lot of smart folks helping with that site...

Answer (score 0):

The discussion above about adding another column was helpful. I came up with this solution with ${ag} providing the given age. The square operation is simpler than checking on the absolution.

```
awk -v a=${ag} '{print $1,$2,$3,($3-a)^2}' | sort -n -k 4
```

Comment: Using the square of the difference reduces the code — it's a good idea.

Comment: That's a good trick. Also need to pipe it to something like `cut -d' ' -f-3` to trim the extra field.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using `perl` instead of `awk`:

```
$ age=30 perl -anE 'push @lines, [@F, abs($ENV{age} - $F[2])];
   END { say join("\t", $_->@[0..2]) for sort { $a->[3] <=> $b->[3] } @lines }' input.txt 
name2   M   31.5
name3   F   20.3
name4   F   55.0
name1   M   73.2
```